# Binding BorderHexColor

Tags: c#, xaml, colors, binding

I have simple problem with binding color. When I try binding BorderHexColor, I get following error:

*No property, bindable property, or event found for 'BorderHexColor', or mismatching type between value and property.*

When:

```
<ffTransformations:RoundedTransformation Radius="240" 
                                         BorderHexColor="#fc0303" 
                                         BorderSize="10"/>
```

The code without binding BorderHexColor works well.

My code:

```
<CollectionView x:Name="collectionStories"
                ItemsSource="{Binding .}"
                HeightRequest="75"
                HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Never"
                ItemsLayout="HorizontalList">
    <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackLayout Margin="5,0,5,0">
                <ff:CachedImage Source="{Binding instagramModel.ProfilePicture}"
                                WidthRequest="50"
                                HeightRequest="50"
                                VerticalOptions="Center"
                                HorizontalOptions="Center">
                    <ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                        <ffTransformations:RoundedTransformation Radius="240" 
                                                                 BorderHexColor="{Binding HexColor}" 
                                                                 BorderSize="10"/>
                    </ff:CachedImage.Transformations>
                    <ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                        <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="InstaStory_Tapped"/>
                    </ff:CachedImage.GestureRecognizers>
                </ff:CachedImage>
                <Label Text="{Binding instagramModel.Username}"
                       TextColor="Gray"
                       FontSize="Small"
                       VerticalOptions="Center"
                       HorizontalOptions="Center"/>
            </StackLayout>
        </DataTemplate>
    </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
</CollectionView>
```

My class:

```
public class InstaStories
    {
        public InstagramModel instagramModel { get; set; }
        public Post Post { get; set; }
        public bool IsSeen { get; set; }

        public string HexColor
        {
            get
            {
                if (!IsSeen)
                {
                    return "#fc0303";
                }
                else
                {
                    return "#28fc03";
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you add the definition of the BorderHexColor property?

Comment: It is: string FFImageLoading.Transformations.RoundedTransformation.BorderHexColor { get; set; }

Comment: you need to add a dependency property. public static $type$ Get$property$(DependencyObject obj)
{
    return ($type$)obj.GetValue($property$Property);
}
public static void Set$property$(DependencyObject obj, $type$ value)
{
    obj.SetValue($property$Property, value);
}
public static readonly DependencyProperty $property$Property =
    DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(nameof($property$), typeof($type$), typeof($ownerclass$), new PropertyMetadata($defaultvalue$));

Comment: Thank you, and why for example binding instagramModel does not need this?

Answer (score 0):

I beleive you will need a value converter.  When XAML is compiled, the system automatically converts the hex string into a color.  But it cannot do this when you bind to a string.  Alternatively, you can bind to a color and convert in code behind before you provide the color value.